# Plugin PHP file gives error 500

Tags: php, 500-internal-error

I have created a plugin with a form to send a post request to a custom PHP file, but when I send the form, I get a 500 error.

To verify and ascertain that the error is not originating from my code I've created a simple HTML file with the same code and run a counter-test on it, to accessing through a GET request: I got no error (HTTP 500 error); I was able to access it successfully.

But: when I change the file extension from ***`.html`*** to ***`.php`***, I get the same 500 error.

I have tried changing file permissions to 777.

Below is the HTML form of the plugin I'm developing *(which gives me a 500 error)*:

```
<form action="http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/plugin-folder/form_processing.php" method="post">
    <!-- form content here -->
</form>
```

Here, content of another simple HTML file:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- something -->
    </body>
</html>
```

When I change the file extension from ***`.html`*** to ***`.php`***, it gives 500 error resulting from the GET request and I can't seem to determine the cause.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please **[edit] your question**, and add [debug information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress).

Comment: You shouldn't be using a standalone file as a form processor, you can use the same URL your form lives at to process the submission

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 500 Internal Server Error is a very general HTTP status code that means something has gone wrong on the web site's server.

You have to enable the `debug` true to understand what is the problem.

Open the `wp-config.php` file. To enable debugging mode, change `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` line to the `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in `wp-config.php` file. Then you can find the what is the error.

Comment: Thanks! that worked. I can see the errors now. I had to turn on another properties such as display_errors.